# Split String by Number regex

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to split a string (keeping all groups) by a number value.  For example `datasource10` would give `["datasource","10"]`.

I've tried using:

```
String[] key = "datasource10".split("(?=\\d)");
```

However thats not returning "10", but rather `["datasource","1","0"]`.  How can I change it to return `["datasource","10"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition which will also require the left side to be a non-digit (`\D`). To do so you can use a [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) like:

```
.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)")
```

But current solution will split in a way `foo123bar`->`foo` `123bar` since you are only splitting between non-digit|digit.

If you would also want to split between `123bar` (digit|non-digit) simply reverse current regex and add it with OR operator like

```
.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you